# Managing LOGGED_IN state on website with SESSION & COOKIE

Tags: php

I am currently working on a website and I am having hard time understand how can I make a secure and flexible system where I can manage user's logged in state.

I am aware of `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE` and I understand how they work, however, I can't find a way to use them properly.

Here is a piece of code that I built for keeping track of whether the user is signed in or not.

state_handler.php

```
include_once(__DIR__ . '/../setup.php');
include_once(COOKIE_UTIL_PATH);
include_once(SESSION_UTIL_PATH);

if (is_session_set() === FALSE) {
    if (is_cookie_set() === TRUE) {
        include_once(DB_PATH);
        $data = get_cookie_data();
        $user = select_user_by_username($data['username']);

        if (!$user || strcmp($data['password'], $user['password']) !== 0) {
            destroy_cookie();
            header('Location: /index.php');
            exit();
        }

        session_start();
        set_session_params($user);

        $new_data = array(
            'username' => $user['username'],
            'password' => $user['password']
        );

        create_cookie($new_data);

    } else if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/src/signin/signin.php') === FALSE) {
        header('Location: /src/signin/signin.php');
        exit();
    }
} else if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/src/signin/signin.php') !== FALSE) {
    header('Location: /index.php');
    exit();
}
```

cookie_util.php

```
function create_cookie(array $data): void
{
    setcookie(
        'user_information',
        json_encode($data),
        [
            'expires' => time() + 1296000,
            'path' => '/',
            'httponly' => true,
            'samesite' => 'Strict'
        ]
    );
}

function is_cookie_set(): bool
{
    return isset($_COOKIE['user_information']);
}

function get_cookie_data(): array
{
    return json_decode($_COOKIE['user_information'], true);
}

function destroy_cookie(): void
{
    setcookie(
        'user_information',
        '',
        [
            'expires' => time() - 1296000,
            'path' => '/',
            'httponly' => true,
            'samesite' => 'Strict'
        ]
    );

    setcookie(
        'PHPSESSID',
        '',
        time() - 1296000,
        '/'
    );
}
```

session_util.php

```
function set_session_params(array $params): void
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

    $_SESSION['id'] = $params['id'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $params['username'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $params['password'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $params['name'];
    $_SESSION['surname'] = $params['surname'];
    $_SESSION['group_id'] = $params['group_id'];
    $_SESSION['team_id'] = $params['team_id'];
    $_SESSION['city_id'] = $params['city_id'];
}

function is_session_set(): bool
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

    return isset($_SESSION['id']);
}

function destroy_session(): void
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}
```

Once user signs in, he is sent a cookie with his Username and Password(hashed with MD5).
This cookie will live for 30 days. If the session expires, I then extract data from the cookie and compare it with DB data. If it works, then I simply start another session and refresh cookie's lifetime.

However, after giving it a bit more thought, this solution is quite problematic.

1. I am storing user's credentials (doesn't matter hashed or not) in cookies, which I think is a safety hazard.
2. I have no way of terminating user's logged in state as an admin. Even if I delete him from DB the user will stay active until the session expires, which is not something I want.

What would be the correct way of solving this? I've been doing this for a little more than a month and don't have lots of experience with website development, so please, help me out here.

Comment: As a side note to anything session and cookie related: 1) you should **never** have your passwords in plain text in the database; and 2) you should **never** use MD5 to hash passwords. Store the result of [password_hash](https://www.php.net/password_hash) and check it with [password_verify](https://www.php.net/password_verify) on the line where you're currently using `strcmp`.

Comment: Is that means you saving password in cookie `(sent a cookie with his Username and Password(hashed with MD5))` ?

Comment: @Dlk yes, I send a cookie with username and password inside a cookie. I know that it is not a good solution, which is why I am looking for advice on how can I keep track whether the user is logged in or not without doing this

Comment: You shouldn't store the password in the session. Just check it upon post request.

Comment: That is very danger, you can set random password and validate with that instead of real password. see this example https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234821/php-secure-remember-me-for-login-using-php-session-and-cookies-with-referer-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most important rules in web programming is **never trust any information sent by the client (browser)**.

Although you have code to set the cookie, the value you see on the next request is not under your control: there is nothing to stop the user pressing F12 in their browser, and setting the cookie themselves.

This is why the concept of *sessions* was invented: the cookie you send to the browser is just a random ID, and the browser can neither read nor write the actual data you've associated with that ID.

So:

- Don't set a custom cookie, just use the session; PHP will manage the cookie for you
- You don't need to store the user's password, hashed or otherwise, to know that they're logged in
- Even once a user's logged in, you can check in the database as often as you like to see if they've been disabled; this might be every request, every 5 minutes, or every time they do something particularly dangerous

Some **very rough** code, which you **should read as an example not just copy and paste** might look like this:

```php
session_start();

if ( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) ) {
    $user = select_user_by_username($_POST['username']);
    if ( password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password_hash']) ) {
        $_SESSION['login_successful'] = true;
        $_SESSION['login_expires_at'] = strtotime('+30 minutes');
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
    }
}

if ( 
    ! $_SESSION['login_successful']
    || $_SESSION['login_expires_at'] < time() 
    || user_is_disabled($_SESSION['user_id'])
) {
    redirect_to_login_page();
    exit;
}

// Extend the login to be 30 minutes from last activity, not 30 minutes from login
$_SESSION['login_expires_at'] = strtotime('+30 minutes');
```

Comment: Yes, this looks good and something I can wrap my head around. But here is the problem:  Lets say the session is set for +30 minutes. User closes the browser and doesn't use the website until tomorrow. Next day he goes on the website again, but he is logged out, so he has to sign-in again. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: @Rey Then make the session longer. Either they are still logged in (= session has not expired) or they are not (= need to re-authenticate).